# Type error: Type 'Binding element 'startReason' implicitly has an 'any' type.' error while building the project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm relatively new to react. I have a project, and it has several components, and among these components is this DateRangePicker component.

I call these events in another component, but when I write the code, I have this one error while building the project.

ERROR:

```
Binding element 'startReason' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Code:

```
import { DateRange, LocalizationProvider, MobileDateRangePicker } from "@mui/lab";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { Query } from "api/Models";
import { useState } from "react";

interface DatePickerProps {
  state: Query;
  params: (keyof Query)[];
  labels: string[];
  fx: (q: Query) => void;
}
export default function BasicDateRangePicker(props: DatePickerProps) {
  const [error, setError] = useState([null, null]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(props.state);
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState<DateRange<Date>>([
    query.dateFrom ? new Date(query.dateFrom) : null,
    query.dateTo ? new Date(query.dateTo) : null,
  ]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <MobileDateRangePicker
        startText={props.labels[0]}
        endText={props.labels[1]}
        value={selectedDate}
        onError={([startReason, endReason], [start, end]) => {
          //work around for same day error
          if (startReason === "invalidRange" && (start as Date).getTime() === (end as Date).getTime()) {
            setError([null, null]);
            return;
          }
          setError([startReason as null, endReason as null]);
        }}
        onChange={(date) => {
          if (date[0]) setQuery(Object.assign(query, { [props.params[0]]: date[0].toISOString().split("T")[0] }));
          if (date[1]) setQuery(Object.assign(query, { [props.params[1]]: date[1].toISOString().split("T")[0] }));

          props.fx(query);
          handleDateChange(date);
        }}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => {
          return (
            <>
              {/* // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
            // @ts-ignore */}
              <TextField
                {...startProps}
                variant="standard"
                error={Boolean(error[0])}
                FormHelperTextProps={{ style: { color: "transparent", height: 0 } }}
              />
              <Box style={{ margin: "auto 10px auto" }}> to </Box>
              {/* // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
            // @ts-ignore */}
              <TextField
                {...endProps}
                variant="standard"
                error={Boolean(error[0])}
                FormHelperTextProps={{ style: { color: "transparent", height: 0 } }}
              />
            </>
          );
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What’s the type signature of the onError callback prop?

Comment: It says 'any' when I hover over the onError callback prop